# Display \u0096 in a jsp

Tags: jsp, unicode, character-encoding

I'm trying to display a character stored in a database that is the unicode character \u0096. Because of a strange windows-vs-web-browser thing this is a control character in the unicode standard, but web-pages will display it as an En Dash. See @AlanMoore's answer on [Some UTF-8 characters do not show up on browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1398700/some-utf-8-characters-do-not-show-up-on-browser).

I have the following jsp file. I want to display the \u0096 character as an En Dash(A feat that other front-end solutions can accomplish).

```
<%@ page pageEncoding="UTF-8" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"%>
<%@ page session="false" trimDirectiveWhitespaces="true"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>
<!doctype html>
<html>

<c:set var="control" scope="request" value= "b"/>
<c:set var="endash" scope="request" value="a"/>
<% request.setAttribute("control", "\u0096");%>
<% request.setAttribute("endash", "\u2013");%>

Match? 0096: <c:out value="${control}"/> 2013: <c:out value="${endash}"/>
```

The output that I get is

```
Match? 0096:  2013: –
```

What I want is

```
Match? 0096: – 2013: –
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The character denoted by `\0096`, i.e. U+0096, is unambiguously a control character in Unicode, with undefined meaning. This should not be confused with the fact that in the windows-1252 encoding, the *byte* 0x96 denotes U+2013 EN DASH.

Thus, instead of trying to render an invisible character as visible, you should simply *replace* U+0096 by U+2013 or, depending on the actual setup, perhaps *convert* the data you get from the database, converting from windows-1252 to e.g. UTF-16. It is unlikely that the database contains something meant to be U+0096. Rather, it contains bytes that are now being misinterpreted as UTF-16 but are actually windows-1252 encoded representations of characters.

Comment: @jukkakkorpela The fact that it is stored in the java string as the byte <96> indicates that a bad transformation has occured?

Comment: @CynicalOptimist, yes, most probably.